# Can I test my app as a developer without being whitelisted by twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

Im making an Android app that requires a sign up/login with twitter option, but to do this i need to pull in the users registered twitter email address.

Since twitter requires that my app is placed on a "white list" before i can use the relevant call i don't know how to test if my code works.

So back to my question, can I test whether I am pulling in a my twitter email correctly when I test my app without being on twitters white list?

I am using fabric 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric and Twitter here.

If you're looking to see the user's email address, your app does need to be whitelisted first. There isn't a test setting currently.

Comment: Thanks Mike, so I can't test it while I wait for it to be white listed? Just to get my email for example

Comment: @MichaelStoddart - That's correct, in order to help combat abuse or spam, any request for email addresses need to be whitelisted and approved beforehand.